# Jensen-Shannon Distance - Estimating the discrete probability distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, histogram, kullback-leibler

In my current research, I am working with a comprehensive dataset that captures human mobility patterns across different locations. My specific focus is on quantifying the similarity between these distributions, using a feature called "median dwell time," which represents the median duration individuals spend in various locations. To accomplish this, I am contemplating the use of the Jensen-Shannon Divergence (JSD) metric, both within different categories of Points of Interest (POIs) and across different cities.

However, a crucial prerequisite for computing the JSD metric is the estimation of discrete probabilities. I'm uncertain about the best approach to creating these probabilities.

One approach I'm considering is constructing a histograg and a constant values to avoid 0 probabilities

```
# Function to calculate JSD for a pair of cities
def calculate_jsd(data1, data2):
p1 = np.histogram(data1, 24)[0] + 0.000001
p1 = p1 / np.sum(p1)

p2 = np.histogram(data2, 24)[0] + 0.000001
p2 = p2 / np.sum(p2)

return distance.jensenshannon(p1, p2)
```

The second approach I'm considering is kernel density estimation (KDE).

```
def calculate_kde_and_normalize_JSD(data1, data2, num_points=24):
# Calculate KDE for data1 and data2
kde1 = scipy.stats.gaussian_kde(data1)
kde2 = scipy.stats.gaussian_kde(data2)

# Create an array of values for the PDF
X = np.linspace(min(data1.min(), data2.min()), max(data1.max(), data2.max()), num_points)

# Calculate the PDFs using KDE
p = kde1(X)
q = kde2(X)
# Normalize the PDFs to sum to 1
p /= np.sum(p)
q /= np.sum(q)
return distance.jensenshannon(p, q)
```

I also have the below code example of my calculation if I consider PDF instead, and I want some advice if this is the right approach in statistic:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Assuming my data in x1 and x2
x1 = test[test['city'] == 'Golden Hills']['median_dwell'].tolist()
x2 = test[test['city'] == 'Detroit']['median_dwell'].tolist()

# Determine the number of bins using Freedman-Diaconis rule
num_bins = int(np.ceil(2 * (len(x1) ** (1/3))))

# Determine the range based on my data
min_value = min(min(x1), min(x2))
max_value = max(max(x1), max(x2))

# Create histograms with dynamically determined bins and range
hist1 = np.histogram(x1, bins=num_bins, range=(min_value, max_value))
hist1_dist = scipy.stats.rv_histogram(hist1)
hist2 = np.histogram(x2, bins=num_bins, range=(min_value, max_value))
hist2_dist = scipy.stats.rv_histogram(hist2)

# Define evaluation points for PDFs
num_points = 100  #assumption
X = np.linspace(min_value, max_value, num_points)

# Calculate PDFs at the specified evaluation points
Y1 = hist1_dist.pdf(X)
Y2 = hist2_dist.pdf(X)


# Compute Jensen-Shannon Distance
M = (Y1 + Y2) / 2
d1 = scipy.stats.entropy(Y1, M, base=2)
d2 = scipy.stats.entropy(Y2, M, base=2)
js_dv = (d1 + d2) / 2
js_distance = np.sqrt(js_dv)
print(f'Jensen-Shannon Distance: {js_distance}')
```

[image]
Jensen-Shannon Distance: 0.0945012408944263

However, the KDE calculation would have completely different results:

```
    import numpy as np
import scipy.stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Assuming your data is in x1 and x2
x1 = test[test['city'] == 'Golden Hills']['median_dwell'].tolist()
x2 = test[test['city'] == 'Detroit']['median_dwell'].tolist()

# Create KDE estimations for x1 and x2
kde1 = scipy.stats.gaussian_kde(x1)
kde2 = scipy.stats.gaussian_kde(x2)

# Define evaluation points for PDFs
num_points = 100  # You can adjust this number based on your preference
min_value = min(min(x1), min(x2))
max_value = max(max(x1), max(x2))
X = np.linspace(min_value, max_value, num_points)

# Calculate PDFs using KDE at the specified evaluation points
Y1 = kde1(X)
Y2 = kde2(X)

# Compute Jensen-Shannon Distance
M = (Y1 + Y2) / 2
d1 = scipy.stats.entropy(Y1, M, base=2)
d2 = scipy.stats.entropy(Y2, M, base=2)
js_dv = (d1 + d2) / 2
js_distance = np.sqrt(js_dv)
print(f'Jensen-Shannon Distance: {js_distance}')enter code here
```

[image]
Jensen-Shannon Distance: 0.3110560464721506
I would greatly appreciate any insights or recommendations on these approaches or any alternative methods that might be more suitable for my analysis. Thank you!